# .addClass misses the final dynamically created element using for loops in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to add a unique class to dynamically created divs using a for loop and .addClass with jquery. The loop is successfully adding the unique class to all of the created divs, except for the final iteration (.square143 in this situation).

The for loop is also adding a uniform class to all of these dynamically created elements (.art), and is doing so successfully.

Another issue I'm having, which could be related to this one, is that the program is creating double the anticipated divs.

Basically, I'm trying to add a unique class to the final iteration div created by the for loop.

```js
function addElementEllsworth () {

  //For loop will dynamically create specified number of empty divs
  for (var i = 0; i < 144; i++) {

    //Actually creating divs here
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");

    //Giving all the created divs for ability to change CSS of entire grid
    $(function() {
        $("div").addClass("art");
    });

    //Giving each individual div a unique class. Then assigning a random color (RGB value) to that class using function.
    $("div").each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass("square" + i);
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', randomEllsworthColor());
    });

    //Putting them into the body of the file
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);

  }

} addElementEllsworth ();

//This function will return a random color (RGB value). The function forms the return value by assembling the proper RGB syntax and random numbers created in a different function.
function randomColor () {

      var maxRGBValue = 255;

      var r = generateRandom(maxRGBValue);
      var g = generateRandom(maxRGBValue);
      var b = generateRandom(maxRGBValue);

      var theColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";

      return theColor;
}


//Returns a hex value associated with Kelly's Spectrum painting at the SFMOMA
function randomEllsworthColor () {

    //Color hexes taken from the Ellsworth Kelly painting at the SFMOMA
    ellsworthColors = ["#2f2d2d","#c6becd","#ff8635","#3b354c","#94d35a","#f7f25e","#0170c1","#243881","#703550","#b38cb9","#7bc653","#do2624","#f2a00f","#f3e44e"];

    //Function returns a value from the above array. Index is randomly selected by generating a random index from the array.
    return ellsworthColors[generateRandom(ellsworthColors.length)];
}

function generateRandom (num) {

    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(num));
}
```

```css
.art {

  float:left;
  width: 08.33333333%;
  padding-bottom: 08.333333%; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
  margin:0%;
  background-color: cyan; /* commenting will hide all colorless square */

}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ellsworth.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery with native DOM APIs like that? And that `$()` thing to add the "art" class; why is that wrapped up as a jQuery "dom ready" handler?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I quite understand your question (I'm new to this). why I'm mixing jquery and native dom — as far as I know that's the only way to dynamically apply CSS to a class? As for adding the $() to the "art" class — Should I have been using .className to classify it? Is jquery a poor solution for that?

Comment: Well that's not true.

Comment: Is there a better way to apply a randomly-generated color to a class? Or a "right" way for that matter?

Comment: Well you *are* using jQuery to set the color. My question is more about why you're using the native APIs.

Comment: When you refer to the native APIs, are you referring to things like document.createElement? I don't have a great "why" for why I'm using them, other than that's the way I know how to create a new element. Basically, I'm not sure of the best practices in terms of when/if you should mix plain js with jquery. Hopefully, that's addressing your question?

Comment: Yes. With jQuery, `$("<div/>")` creates a new `<div>` element. You can pass a second argument to initialize it: `$("<div/>", { "class": "art" })`.

Comment: Oh, interesting — thank you for following up! Most of the jQuery I've been implementing has been the result of finding questions/answers similar to what I've been trying to do. I'll have to look up some tutorials to learn it the proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that last div does not have the class you expect is that `$("div").each(function(i) {` selects divs already on the page, when in your code the newest `div` has not yet been added to the page until `document.body.insertBefore`.

I've created a pen to show how your code could look without JQuery i.e. using plain Javascript.

https://codepen.io/theleebriggs/pen/XEeMve

Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked perfectly — thank you! If anyone else also has this issue, it seems that moving the "document.body.insertBefore" ahead of the ".each" function will also solve this.